# How to manually position ASP.Net Chart Legend?

Tags: c#, asp.net, charts, legend

Using the Chart controls built into ASP.Net, I'm trying to manually position the Title and the Legend so that they are directly next to each other horizontally just above the ChartArea. I've been able to manually position the Title using the following code:

```
chart.Titles["Title1"].Position.Auto = false;
chart.Titles["Title1"].Position.X = 10;
chart.Titles["Title1"].Position.Y = 5;
```

There's nothing to it, really. However, I'm attempting to position the Legend to the right of it with the following code, and the Legend doesn't even appear:

```
chart.Legends["Legend1"].Position.Auto = false;
chart.Legends["Legend1"].Position.X = 30;
chart.Legends["Legend1"].Position.Y = 5;
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong? This seems like it should be relatively simple. I've even tried various other coordinates, and I can't get the Legend to appear anywhere. It does appear if I use the built-in positioning such as below, but this positioning does not suit my purposes:

```
chart.Legends["Legend1"].Docking = Docking.Top;
chart.Legends["Legend1"].DockedToChartArea = "ChartArea1";
chart.Legends["Legend1"].IsDockedInsideChartArea = false;
chart.Legends["Legend1"].Alignment = StringAlignment.Far;
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try newing up an `ElementPosition` object, like this:

```
chart.Legends["Legend1"].Position.Auto = false;
chart.Legends["Legend1"].Position = new ElementPosition(30, 5, 100, 20);
```

Note: The constructor for `ElementPosition` takes 0 or 4 parameters (x, y, width, height).

Comment: That worked! Thank you very much. It actually seems that the lack of setting the `Legend.Position.Width` and `Legend.Position.Height` was the culprit. I was able to get my code to work just by adding these. I do prefer your one line `new` method, though, so I'll be using that instead.

Answer (score 7):

I stumbled on this question for looking how to move legend at the bottom of a chart.

Answer for that is to use `Docking` property

```
Chart1.Legends["Legend1"].Docking = Docking.Bottom;
```

It may be helpful for someone in future, as this is the first link in google search.